# fastest way to determine actual rendered height of some DOM element that not exists in document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, getboundingclientrect

I need to create some DOM element and calculate their actual rendered height. I write some code to first create all of them and insert them to document, and then calculate their height using getBoundingClientRect method. But the number of element is big and time of this process is too long for my application. Is there any faster way to do this?

```
// first create all element -> list
// insert all of them to document
console.time("for");
for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    heights[i] = list[i].getBoundingClientRect().height;
}
console.timeEnd("for");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the size of the element, if you just want the height you can try these, I don't know if they're faster.

```
document.getElementById('myDiv').clientHeight;
document.getElementById('myDiv').offsetHeight;
```

**clientHeight** includes padding.
**offsetHeight** includes padding, border and scrollBar